# How to display all images from all entities with alt attribute?

Tags: views, files, media, blocks

I have a problem with viewing all the images uploaded to the site.

I need to show images that uploaded to nodes, terms, bean blocks. They are using different image fields, so that means that they use different tables. I could use views and show files filtered by mimetype, but the problem is that I need also to show alt attribute and a link to the content this image related to whether it is a node or term or bean block